# No form exist when I tested changing password in django-allauth

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-allauth, django-webtest

I want to write a test that will test change the password in the application.
I use the django-allauth.
For testing, I use django-WebTest.

When I run my code, I get the message:

```
FAILED (errors=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
(urlop)mariusz@mariusz-K73E:~/myapp$ python manage.py test users
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
.E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_password_change_use_template (myapp.users.tests.ChangePasswordTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mark/myapp/users/tests.py", line 16, in test_password_change_use_template
    password_change.form['oldpassword'] = "test123"
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/urlop/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webtest/response.py", line 56, in form
    "You used response.form, but no forms exist")
TypeError: You used response.form, but no forms exist
```

Here is my test code:

```
from django_webtest import WebTest
from django_dynamic_fixture import G
from users.models import User
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class ChangePasswordTest(WebTest):
    def setUp(self):
        self.user = G(User)

    def test_password_change_code(self):
        password_change = self.app.get(reverse('account_change_password'), user=self.user)

    def test_password_change_use_template(self):
        password_change = self.app.get(reverse('account_change_password'), user=self.user)
        password_change.form['oldpassword'] = "test123"
        password_change.form['password1'] = "test456"
        password_change.form['password2'] = "test456"
        password_change.form.submit()
        self.assertRedirects(password_change, reverse('change_password'))
```